# how to remove all whitespaces in front and beind 3 consecutive periods

Tags: bash, sed, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to remove all white spaces before and after 3 consecutive periods and replace it with the actual ellipse symbol.

I've tried the following code:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*\.\.\.[[:space:]]*/…/g'
```

It replaces the 3 periods with the ellipse symbol, but the spaces before and after remain.

Sample Input.

```
hello    ...   world
```

Desired output

```
hello…world
```

Comment: Your sed command [seems to work](https://ideone.com/B4dUFX).

Comment: `but the spaces before and after remain` - no they don't, your command works.

Comment: My code does apparently work. I got confused because unbeknown to me the input file had already ellipse symbols whose spaces weren't being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression you are using is ERE(extended regular expressions) you have to add `-E` option to `sed` as follows to allow it, since you are using character classes in your code `[[:space:]]`.

```
sed -E 's/[[:space:]]*\.\.\.[[:space:]]*/.../g'   Input_file
```

Without -`E` try:

```
sed 's/ *\.\.\. */.../g'  Input_file
```

Comment: I need to do it without adding -e or -r flag. How would I do it?

Comment: @HenryM, You need to remove character classes in case you don't want to deal with ERE in your code and don't want `-E` option, check my 2nd solution and let me know then?

Comment: Same bug as min have,  try four dots and you get: `hello....   world` and not `hello` 
  ....   world` since its 4 dots, it should not do any ting, I think.

Comment: @HenryM, I believe while copying your sample code, some ambiguous character came too :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `sed`

```
echo "hello    ...   world" | sed -E 's/ +(\.\.\.) +/\1/g'
hello...world
```

4 dots, do nothing?

```
echo "hello    ....   world" | sed -E 's/ +(\.\.\.) +/\1/g'
hello    ....   world
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash, just use parameter substitution...

```
foo="hello    ...    world"
foo="${foo//+( )...+( )/...}"
```

Now, `echo "$foo"`, outputs:

```
hello...world
```

The syntax for BaSH regex variable substitution are as follows:

```
${var-name/search/replace}
```

A single `/`replaces only the first occurrence from the left, while a double `//`replaces every occurrence.

One of `?*+@!` followed by `(pattern-list)` replaces a specified number of occurrences of the patterns in pattern-list as follows:

```
? Zero or one occurrence
* Zero or more occurrences
+ One or more occurrences
@ A single occurence
! Anything that *doesn't* match one of the occurrences
```

Pattern list can be any combination of literal strings, or character classes, separated by the pipe character `|`